# Why is this code giving unexpected results?

Tags: c++, stdin

When I try to run this piece of code-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

long long fact(long long k)
{   return k/5 + k/25;
}
int main()
{
     long long n,k;
    scanf("%lld %lld", &n,&k);
    while(n--)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&k);
    printf("%d\n",fact(k));
}
}
```

with stdinput-

```
4
1
8
26
52
```

the output I get is-

```
1
6
12
12
```

instead of 0 1 6 12 .

Can someone explain this unexpected result ?

Comment: Why not step through your algorithm line-by-line on paper and find out? :) Isn't that first `scanf` call suspicious? You never enter two numbers on a single line. For all I know that's valid as I do not use ancient and obsolete technology like `scanf`.

Comment: I have also tried using `cin cout` instead of `scanf printf` but still the code fails

Comment: Now would be a good time to start to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: `"%d"` in your `printf` doesn't print `long long int`, it prints `int`. It should be `"%lld"`

Comment: Please note that I have rolled back your last edit - editing your code invalidates earlier comments/answers and makes the question less useful to future visitors.

Comment: Still that's no reason not to use technology from _within_ the last 25 years.

Comment: Apart from an unnecessary `iostream` and illadvised `using namespace std` this is C code, not C++.

Comment: "I have also tried using cin cout instead of scanf printf but still the code fails" instead of breaking the problem down to a simpler one of fetching and printing just one value? Then two, and then proceeding to a loop calling a function? I'm not being a jerk here, but the core of your problem is that you don't know what your code is doing. The moment you solve that the problem will be obvious to you. Hth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is broken in two places:

```
int main()
{
    long long n,k;
    scanf("%lld", &n);  // <<< only read n here, not n and k
    while (n--)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &k);
        printf("%lld\n", fact(k));  // <<< use %lld for long long
    }
}
```

Note that if you had compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) then your compiler would have pointed out the second mistake.

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/l9GwJo)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry I missed the first one ;) How do I enable warnings in my compiler. I'm using Gcc 4.8.4 in Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

You are reading an extra `k`, which is not required.

```
scanf("%lld %lld", &n,&k);
```

You don't need to input the above `k` as it is not used, but it counts as an input. If you instead have your input this way:

```
 4   // scanf("%lld %lld", &n,&k); --> reads n 
 1   // scanf("%lld %lld", &n,&k); --> reads k
 1   // scanf("%lld", &k); --> reads k for n=4
 8   // scanf("%lld", &k); --> reads k for n=3
 26  // scanf("%lld", &k); --> reads k for n=2 
 52  // scanf("%lld", &k); --> reads k for n=1
```

You would get the correct output. So remove the extra argument in scanf:

```
 scanf("%lld",&n);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first value that is passed in long long fact method is 8.
So your output will be 1. k first value is overwritten by second call.